# list object not callable project euler 59

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to do project euler problem 59, i am having an issue in that one of the necessary methods won't work as the program returns:

```
xorNum =  test(f,j)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.
```

Both `f` and `j` are integers and when I used the test method with two random integers, it worked perfectly. Does anyone have any ideas why it may not be working?

```
def main():
    cipherText = """79,59,12,2,79,35,8,28,20,2,3,68,8,9,68,45,0,12,9,67,68,4,7,5,23,27,1,21,79,85,78,79,85,71,38,10,71,27,12,2,79,6,2,8,13,9,1,13,9,8,68,19,7,1,71,56,11,21,11,68,6,3,22,2,14,0,30,79,1,31,6,23,19,10,0,73,79,44,2,79,19,6,28,68,16,6,16,15,79,35,8,11,72,71,14,10,3,79,12,2,79,19,6,28,68,32,0,0,73,79,86,71,39,1,71,24,5,20,79,13,9,79,16,15,10,68,5,10,3,14,1,10,14,1,3,71,24,13,19,7,68,32,0,0,73,79,87,71,39,1,71,12,22,2,14,16,2,11,68,2,25,1,21,22,16,15,6,10,0,79,16,15,10,22,2,79,13,20,65,68,41,0,16,15,6,10,0,79,1,31,6,23,19,28,68,19,7,5,19,79,12,2,79,0,14,11,10,64,27,68,10,14,15,2,65,68,83,79,40,14,9,1,71,6,16,20,10,8,1,79,19,6,28,68,14,1,68,15,6,9,75,79,5,9,11,68,19,7,13,20,79,8,14,9,1,71,8,13,17,10,23,71,3,13,0,7,16,71,27,11,71,10,18,2,29,29,8,1,1,73,79,81,71,59,12,2,79,8,14,8,12,19,79,23,15,6,10,2,28,68,19,7,22,8,26,3,15,79,16,15,10,68,3,14,22,12,1,1,20,28,72,71,14,10,3,79,16,15,10,68,3,14,22,12,1,1,20,28,68,4,14,10,71,1,1,17,10,22,71,10,28,19,6,10,0,26,13,20,7,68,14,27,74,71,89,68,32,0,0,71,28,1,9,27,68,45,0,12,9,79,16,15,10,68,37,14,20,19,6,23,19,79,83,71,27,11,71,27,1,11,3,68,2,25,1,21,22,11,9,10,68,6,13,11,18,27,68,19,7,1,71,3,13,0,7,16,71,28,11,71,27,12,6,27,68,2,25,1,21,22,11,9,10,68,10,6,3,15,27,68,5,10,8,14,10,18,2,79,6,2,12,5,18,28,1,71,0,2,71,7,13,20,79,16,2,28,16,14,2,11,9,22,74,71,87,68,45,0,12,9,79,12,14,2,23,2,3,2,71,24,5,20,79,10,8,27,68,19,7,1,71,3,13,0,7,16,92,79,12,2,79,19,6,28,68,8,1,8,30,79,5,71,24,13,19,1,1,20,28,68,19,0,68,19,7,1,71,3,13,0,7,16,73,79,93,71,59,12,2,79,11,9,10,68,16,7,11,71,6,23,71,27,12,2,79,16,21,26,1,71,3,13,0,7,16,75,79,19,15,0,68,0,6,18,2,28,68,11,6,3,15,27,68,19,0,68,2,25,1,21,22,11,9,10,72,71,24,5,20,79,3,8,6,10,0,79,16,8,79,7,8,2,1,71,6,10,19,0,68,19,7,1,71,24,11,21,3,0,73,79,85,87,79,38,18,27,68,6,3,16,15,0,17,0,7,68,19,7,1,71,24,11,21,3,0,71,24,5,20,79,9,6,11,1,71,27,12,21,0,17,0,7,68,15,6,9,75,79,16,15,10,68,16,0,22,11,11,68,3,6,0,9,72,16,71,29,1,4,0,3,9,6,30,2,79,12,14,2,68,16,7,1,9,79,12,2,79,7,6,2,1,73,79,85,86,79,33,17,10,10,71,6,10,71,7,13,20,79,11,16,1,68,11,14,10,3,79,5,9,11,68,6,2,11,9,8,68,15,6,23,71,0,19,9,79,20,2,0,20,11,10,72,71,7,1,71,24,5,20,79,10,8,27,68,6,12,7,2,31,16,2,11,74,71,94,86,71,45,17,19,79,16,8,79,5,11,3,68,16,7,11,71,13,1,11,6,1,17,10,0,71,7,13,10,79,5,9,11,68,6,12,7,2,31,16,2,11,68,15,6,9,75,79,12,2,79,3,6,25,1,71,27,12,2,79,22,14,8,12,19,79,16,8,79,6,2,12,11,10,10,68,4,7,13,11,11,22,2,1,68,8,9,68,32,0,0,73,79,85,84,79,48,15,10,29,71,14,22,2,79,22,2,13,11,21,1,69,71,59,12,14,28,68,14,28,68,9,0,16,71,14,68,23,7,29,20,6,7,6,3,68,5,6,22,19,7,68,21,10,23,18,3,16,14,1,3,71,9,22,8,2,68,15,26,9,6,1,68,23,14,23,20,6,11,9,79,11,21,79,20,11,14,10,75,79,16,15,6,23,71,29,1,5,6,22,19,7,68,4,0,9,2,28,68,1,29,11,10,79,35,8,11,74,86,91,68,52,0,68,19,7,1,71,56,11,21,11,68,5,10,7,6,2,1,71,7,17,10,14,10,71,14,10,3,79,8,14,25,1,3,79,12,2,29,1,71,0,10,71,10,5,21,27,12,71,14,9,8,1,3,71,26,23,73,79,44,2,79,19,6,28,68,1,26,8,11,79,11,1,79,17,9,9,5,14,3,13,9,8,68,11,0,18,2,79,5,9,11,68,1,14,13,19,7,2,18,3,10,2,28,23,73,79,37,9,11,68,16,10,68,15,14,18,2,79,23,2,10,10,71,7,13,20,79,3,11,0,22,30,67,68,19,7,1,71,8,8,8,29,29,71,0,2,71,27,12,2,79,11,9,3,29,71,60,11,9,79,11,1,79,16,15,10,68,33,14,16,15,10,22,73"""


    asciiDict = {} #create ascii table dictionary with number as key
    asciiDict2 = {} #reverse key value of above dictionary
    for char in range(256):
        keyVal =  "%d: %c" % (char, char)           
        slicer = keyVal.index(':')
        key = keyVal[0:slicer]
        val = keyVal[slicer+2:]
        asciiDict[int(key)] = val

    for key in asciiDict.keys():
        newVal = asciiDict[key]
        asciiDict2[newVal] = key
    newlist = [int(n) for n in cipherText.split(',')] 
    #convert cipher text into list of numbers 
    listOfThreeChars = []
    for n in range(len(newlist)):
        listOfThreeChars.append(newlist[n:n+3]) 
        #create list of groups of three consecutive numbers in cipherText
    mostCommonDict = mostCommon(listOfThreeChars)
    mostFrequent3 = mostCommonDict[max(mostCommonDict.keys())] 
     #most common three consecutive numbers, if the key is right these 
     #numbers will become a common three letter word such as 'the'
    print testCipher(asciiDict,asciiDict2, 'jhd', mostFrequent3)

    def testCipher(asciiDict,asciiDict2, cipherKey, cipherExtract):
    cipherKeyAscii = []
    test = []
    output = []
    for k in cipherKey:
        asciiNum = asciiDict2[k]
        cipherKeyAscii.append(asciiNum)
    print cipherKeyAscii
    for i in range(len(cipherKeyAscii)):
        f,j = cipherKeyAscii[i],cipherExtract[i]
        print type(f), type(j),f,j
        xorNum =  test(f,j) #HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
        test.append(xorNum)
    for final in test:
        letter = asciiDict[final]
        output.append(letter)
    return output

    def mostCommon(lst): #find most common three consecutive number combinations in text
    dic = {}
    for three in lst:
        key = three
        count = []
        for n in lst:
            if n == key:
                count.append(1)
        dic[len(count)] = key
    return dic
    #return max(set(sum(lst, [])), key=sum(lst, []).count)


    def toBinary(decimalNumber):
    quotient = 1
    remainder = 0
    tmpNum = decimalNumber
    finalNumberList = []
    n = ""
    #e.g. take 14...
    while quotient != 0:
        remainder = decimalNumber % 2 #14 % 2 = 0
        quotient = decimalNumber / 2 #14 / 2 = 7
        decimalNumber = quotient # 7 % 2 = 1 and so on...
        finalNumberList.insert( 0, remainder )
    # Used because all numbers are in a list, i.e. convert to string
    for num in finalNumberList:
        n += str( num )
    return n


    def XOR(number1, number2):
    number1List = []
    number2List = []
    XORoutput = []
    for i in str(number1): #turn both binary numbers into lists
        number1List.append(int(i))
    for i in str(number2):
        number2List.append(int(i))
    if len(number1List)>len(number2List): #make sure they are same lengths
        diff = len(number1List) - len(number2List)
        for i in range(diff):
            number2List.insert(0,0)
    for i in range(len(number1List)): #XOR it
        if number1List[i] == number2List[i]:
            XORoutput.append(0)
        if number1List[i] != number2List[i]:
            XORoutput.append(1)
    num = int(''.join(map(str,XORoutput))) #turn XOR list into int
    return num




    def test(num1, num2): #convert input to binary and xor and return to integer
    print num1,num2
    bin1 = toBinary(num1) #turn to binary
    bin2 = toBinary(num2)
    xor = XOR(bin1,bin2) #XOR
    output = int(str(xor),2) #return to number
    return output



    if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print main.__doc__
        main()
```

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous 6 questions. Click on the hollowed out check mark next to the answer that best solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You set `test` to a list; you cannot have both a function *and* a list use the same name:

```
def main():
    # other code

    test = []

    # more code

    for i in range(len(cipherKeyAscii)):
        # more irrelevant code

        xorNum =  test(f,j)
        test.append(xorNum)
```

masking the function `test()`. You even use `test` as a list again on the very next line.

Rename the list, or rename the function. Most of all, pick better, clearer names for your variables.

Comment: You must have lightning fingers Martijn.

Comment: thank you so much Martijn, a silly mistake on my part but sometimes you need another set of eyes to see it

Answer (score 1):

You defined `test` to be a list. You also defined it to be a function. De-conflict your names and you should be good to go.